# Convert SVG path to use animateMotion

Tags: html, svg

I'd like to use an  element with svg but I don't know how to properly format my path.

My actual path is

```
<path d="M952 881C1174.57 881 1355 700.571 1355 478C1355 255.429 1174.57 75 952 75C729.429 75 549 255.429 549 478C549 700.571 729.429 881 952 881ZM952 882C1175.12 882 1356 701.123 1356 478C1356 254.877 1175.12 74 952 74C728.877 74 548 254.877 548 478C548 701.123 728.877 882 952 882Z" stroke="lightgrey" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
```

From what I understood from the MDN docs I need a different type of path more like

```
<path d="M10,110 A120,120 -45 0,1 110 10 A120,120 -45 0,1 10,110"
```

with commas. First of all how is this type of path called ? Can I convert somehow mine to fit this structure ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Is it just a circle? Your path is made of 2 fragments (note Z and M appearing in middle of it) and is using spline curves instead of arcs, so it's far from optimal. Beside of that it is formatted just fine, comma or space can be used equally. Why do you think you need it *different*?

Comment: spaces and commas are both valid interchangeable separators.  Your first path are two overlapping circles. Paste the path in: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/

Comment: Either path can be animated with animateMotion. Where in MDN does it say otherwise?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for your answers  ! 

@VasilyLiaskovsky Don't know I couldn't make it work so I thought it needed another formatting. I just exported it straight from Figma quite quickly and I don't know why it's actually two overlapping circles. 

Danny'365CSI'Engelman That tool is awesome thanks !

Answer (score 1):

That path works fine - did you try it?

```html
<svg width="800px" height="600px" viewBox=" 0 0 2000 800">
  
<path d="M952 881C1174.57 881 1355 700.571 1355 478C1355 255.429 1174.57 75 952 75C729.429 75 549 255.429 549 478C549 700.571 729.429 881 952 881ZM952 882C1175.12 882 1356 701.123 1356 478C1356 254.877 1175.12 74 952 74C728.877 74 548 254.877 548 478C548 701.123 728.877 882 952 882Z" stroke="lightgrey" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
  
    <circle r="25" fill="red">
    <animateMotion dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite"
path="M952 881C1174.57 881 1355 700.571 1355 478C1355 255.429 1174.57 75 952 75C729.429 75 549 255.429 549 478C549 700.571 729.429 881 952 881ZM952 882C1175.12 882 1356 701.123 1356 478C1356 254.877 1175.12 74 952 74C728.877 74 548 254.877 548 478C548 701.123 728.877 882 952 882Z"  />
  </circle>
```

Comment: Damn you're right thanks !!